# startactivity(intent) interrupts Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app which allows the user to share some information via other applications (whatsapp, facebook etc). I would like to return to the previous activity once I am done sharing. Here is what I have tried so far-

```
public void ShareSelectedResults()
{
    Intent sharing = new Intent();
    sharing.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String message = MakeMessage(); //compose message, just text
    sharing.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    sharing.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharing, "Share result with"));
    selected_results.clear();       //static array_list emptied
    //ReturnToScoreBoard();         //return to previous activity
}

public void ReturnToScoreBoard()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scoreboard.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Everything works fine, ie I can share my results. But if I add the commented line `ReturnToScoreBoard();` to the code, I return to the previous activity without ever being allowed to share. Is there a method I can use to return to the previous activity only once the sharing intent has been completed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is finish() activity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scoreboard.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);finish();

Comment: Nope, still goes back to previous activity without allowing to share

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity and in onActivityResult, check the request code and if the result is success then call the method ReturnToScoreBoard()

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ReturnToScoreBoard()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scoreboard.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE);
}
```

and then, do as RaviVadera said. In that activity handle like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ReturnToScoreBoard()
    }
}
```

Just thought I would elaborate onRaviVadera's explanation. Hope this helps.